# List files in directory on AWS S3 with pyspark/python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, pyspark

So, I am new to AWS S3 and pyspark and linux. I am not sure where to start. Here is my question:

In linux I can issue the following command and can see files in the folder:

```
aws s3 ls 's3://datastore/L2/parquet'
```

Doing similar thing with python does not work

```
import os
os.listdir('s3://datastore/L2/parquet')
```

It gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3://datastore/L2/parquet'
```

However, `pyspark` and `SQLContext.read.parquet` understands it well:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.parquet('s3://datastore/L2/parquet')
```

Any reason why it works in `SQLContext` and does not work in `os.listdir`? Where can I start to clear my confusion? Any reply besides 'get bachelor in cs' would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, AWS s3 is not the same as your operating system's file system. The AWS `s3 ls` command and the pyspark `SQLContext.read` commands are doing something different from the `os.listdir` command, which does not know how to read things from s3.

To read things from s3, I recommend looking at the boto3 library, or the s3fs library, which is a wrapper around boto3 that treats s3 more like a filesystem. There are a variety of options within boto3 for listing buckets and files within buckets.

From [the s3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html):

In terms of implementation, buckets and objects are resources, and Amazon S3 provides APIs for you to manage them.

If you don't know how the Linux file system works, I recommend reading about it, maybe something like [this](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html) will be helpful.